# Android JUnit don't compile if objects are parcelable

Tags: android, junit, parcelable

I have a very simple class, and I have writen a very simple Junit test which is successfull.

Now I add implements Parcelable to my class. My code compliles well and the app works well, but my Junit test don't compile anymore, because of NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable

I am not trying to test the parcelable properties, I just need my test to compile.

I guess there is a configuration problem but I can't find what to change to fix this.

I work on Android Studio 2.3. I have already tried to restart android studio / rebuild / clean...

Help would be apreciated.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Parcelable

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.example.me.myapp.PropositionUnitTest.isDeltaCPositiveOrNullIsCorrect1(PropositionUnitTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.Parcelable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem a few days ago. It was not an issue before, so I would assume that it might be some sort of a bug introduced recently.

Comment: Ok, after fighting for a few hours I gave up, created a new project, copied all files and the problem was solved. I still have no idea what might have caused that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about.

Comment: I've done the same : create a new projet and copy the files and my tests are now compiling. I wonder what was wront with my config.

Comment: Interestingly, I experienced the problem again when I changed the path of this newly created project. This makes me suspect that it might some sort of a relative path to JDK/SDK/whatever issue. You might also try to move the new project to a different location -- I would be very curious to learn whether the problem occurs again for you.

Answer (score 38):

All of sudden, I started facing the same problem and unlike other's I don't have the option of copy n paste the test files into new project.
What i did is just delete the .gradle and .idea folder from the root directory and build the project. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks! it seems like some sort of studio cache related issue.

Comment: Worked for me even when a restart and Invalidate caches did not

Comment: Works for me. I'm both happy and frustrated to see it's working.... what a weird bug.

Comment: For me, it was enough to remove the .gradle folder

Comment: Hi @Nathalie if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. That solution works. Thanks!

Comment: I could spend hours to fix it. This works for me too. Very strange bug.

Answer (score 18):

I also faced a similar problem. You just have to invalidate caches and restart. This is what I did:

In Android Studio, FILE -> INVALIDATE CACHES/RESTART...

and then press 'Invalidate Caches and Restart' button.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently AS doesn't correctly load Android classes into the classpath for testing sometimes. 
An alternative to having to delete .gradle and .idea files manually is to do clear the caches in AS and do a clean:
    File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
    `./gradlew clean`

Otherwise just run your tests on the terminal `./gradlew test`